# Network Switching

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, ethernet

> Is it possible to switch between Wireless and Wired Connections when
>   **both** are connected **without** switching off either one of the two connections in Ubuntu 18.04?

The thing is that when I want to switch between a connected wireless(WiFi) or wired(Ethernet) network while both connections are connected I literally have to switch either one off to connect to the other it doesn't matter which of the two(WiFi or Ethernet) was the preferred network.

I refer back to the question above is there a way to **switch to your preferred** network without **switching off** the current network that's being used?

Comment: Is it better now @roaima

Comment: Have you considered leaving them both on and just changing your routes instead of turning one off and the other on and vice-versa? You could even write a small script and keep it in your PATH and just use it when you want to switch networks.

Comment: @number9 What do you mean by "changing your routes"? How do I do that?

Comment: Looking at a machine with two interfaces, both on, and then looking at the routes with route -n you should see that both are active and both have a default route (which is what linux does by default). What you want is to favor one over the other, and then switch them. You can do this in several ways, but I think an elegant one would be metrics. Read [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708319/how-to-use-network-metric-to-manage-two-nics-in-one-pc) about setting metrics. You should be able to change the metric in the default routes with a script, then both nets will be up all the time.